# MySQL Update command

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i need to add a special text to all rows in my mysql table , 
how to add some text  to the end of all rows' content in a table just for one field

i used this code :

```
UPDATE `blogs` SET `title`= `title` + 'mytext';
```

but didnt work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UPDATE blogs SET title=concat(title, 'mytext');`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a string concatenation operator (`+`). You have to use the [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function, as [Daniel Schneller pointed out in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450932/mysql-command-for-update/2450938#2450938).

If you try `SELECT '1' + '2';` in MySQL, it would return `3`. The `+` operator is simply an addition operator. Your query would have updated the title field with a `0`.